# plugin:vite:import-analysis Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax

Tags: reactjs, vite

... If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.

I`m using Vite for React and Javascript project.
Just have two JS files and trying to import a variable I created in another file, but it gives the above error.

Here is two files:
file1.js
`export const PAGE_SIZE = 10;`
file2.js
`import {PAGE_SIZE} from "../utils/file1";`

there is literary no more code yet, and it already gave me the error.

I`m not using a JSX syntax, so I`m not sure where the error came from.